# Trying to write shortcode with get_post_meta but isn't working

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, post-meta

I am trying to write a plugin with a CPT and have a shortcode to display the data. I can get 'the_title()' to work and display the title of the post type but using 'get_post_meta()' I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
function ClientDirectoriesCPT() {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_custom_post_type' ) );
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'register_meta_boxes' ) );
    add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_meta_boxes' ) );
    add_shortcode( 'client-directory-page', array( $this, 'build_client_directory_page' ) );
}


function build_client_directory_page( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'client',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ) );
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => null,
    ), $atts));

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        $client_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'client_name', true); ?>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6"><?= the_title(); ?></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6"><?= $client_name ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}

/**
* Registers a Meta Box on our Client Directory Custom Post Type, called 'Client Details'
*/
function register_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'client-details', 'Client Details', array( $this, 'output_meta_box' ), 'client', 'normal', 'high' );
}

/**
* Output a Client Details meta box
*
* @param WP_Post $post WordPress Post object
*/
function output_meta_box( $post ) {
    // 2nd with Name, address, website and description

    $client_name = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_client_name', true );
    $client_address = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_client_address', true );
    $client_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_client_url', true );
    $client_description = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_client_description', true );

    // Add a nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field('save_client', 'clients_nonce' );

    // Output label and field
    echo ('<p><label for="client_name">' . __( 'Name', 'cd-crm' ) . '</label>' );
    echo ('<input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name" value="'.esc_attr( $client_name ).'" /></p>' );

    echo ('<p><label for="client_address">' . __( 'Address', 'cd-crm' ) . '</label>' );
    echo ('<input type="text" name="client_address" id="client_address" value="'.esc_attr( $client_address ).'" /></p>' );

    echo ('<p><label for="client_url">' . __( 'URL', 'cd-crm' ) . '</label>' );
    echo ('<input type="text" name="client_url" id="client_url" value="'.esc_attr( $client_url ).'" /></p>' );

    echo ('<p><label for="client_description">' . __( 'Description', 'cd-crm' ) . '</label>' );
    echo ('<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="client_description" name="client_description">' . esc_html( $client_description ) . '</textarea>' );
}

/**
* Saves the meta box field data
*
* @param int $post_id Post ID
*/
function save_meta_boxes( $post_id ) {

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['clients_nonce'] ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['clients_nonce'], 'save_client' ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Check this is the Contact Custom Post Type
    if ( 'client' != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Check the logged in user has permission to edit this post
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // OK to save meta data
    $client_name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['client_name'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_client_name', $client_name );

    $client_address = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['client_address'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_client_address', $client_address );

    $client_url = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['client_url'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_client_url', $client_url );

    // $client_description = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['client_description'] );
    // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_client_description', $client_description );

    // Save the textarea
    if ( isset( $_POST['client_description'] ) ) {

        // WP's default allowed tags
        global $allowedtags;

        // allow iframe only in this instance
        $iframe = array( 'iframe' => array(
                            'src' => array (),
                            'width' => array (),
                            'height' => array (),
                            'frameborder' => array(),
                            'allowFullScreen' => array() // add any other attributes you wish to allow
                             ) );

        $allowed_html = array_merge( $allowedtags, $iframe );

        // Sanitize user input.
        $my_data = wp_kses( $_POST['client_description'], $allowed_html );

        //$my_data = $_POST['client_description'];

        // Update the meta field in the database.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_client_description', $my_data );
    }

}'
```

Comment: You are using shorthand PHP tags, like <?= /*some stuff*/ ?> they won't work - see [WordPress Coding Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#no-shorthand-php-tags). Besides you are not `echo`'ing the variable `$client_name`.

Comment: If I change it out to this `<div class="col-sm-6"><?php echo $client_name ?></div>` seems it's not working either

Comment: what happens if you use `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`?

Comment: @Milo when I change it to `$client_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'client_name', true ); ?>` nothing displays either

Comment: Inside the the metabox function the post meta name is `_client_name`, so with an additional underscore at the front.

Comment: @ialocin that did it!! Thank you so much. I'm new to PHP and Wordpress...been in Python/Django for years. I'm learning ;) Thank you!! If you post as an answer I'll accept it for you.

Comment: my pleasure, I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several minor problems with your code:

Firstly, you are using shorthand PHP tags, like `<?= /*some stuff*/ ?>` they won't work - see [WordPress Coding Standards - No Shorthand PHP Tags](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#no-shorthand-php-tags).

Secondly, you are not `echo`'ing the variable `$client_name`.

Last but not least, you are saving your post meta with the name `_client_name`, with an additional underscore at the front, but made a typo while trying to get it, the underscore is missing.